# Carl Fredricksen hat. Is it awarded immediately or at end-of-day?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

I would like to know if the *Carl Fredericksen* hat is awarded only at end-of-day or if it is awarded when the 'threshold' of >= 5 upvotes is reached.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'm new here (as you might guess from my LOW rep) and it is really disappointing to get a downvote WITH NO EXPLANATION.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got that hat at the end of the day, and it does make sense because its criteria are:

> at least 5 upvotes from 5 different users in a UTC day with no downvotes

After you've got those 5 upvotes, the UTC day is not necessarily over yet, so you *can* still get a downvote, which would not qualify you for the hat anymore.

Comment: I was not considering the downvote possibility -- now it makes total sense to me.